# Regular expression program doesn't print

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to read data from a file and print the words (one per line) that contain all of the lowercase vowels ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') in order. they don't need to be next to each other

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#$data_file = "words.txt;
open (MYFILE, $data_file) or die "can't find file - $!";

while (<MYFILE> =~ m/.*a.*e.*i.*o.*u.*/i)
{
    print "$_";
}

close(MYFILE);
```

it is not printing anything :/

Comment: Wow! Not obvios behavior and good imagination! :) strict and warnings will prevent such magic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't the regular expression, but how you use the file handle, try this:

```
while (<MYFILE>) {
    print if /.*a.*e.*i.*o.*u.*/i;
}
```

Comment: Could drop the leading and trailing `.*`, too.

Answer (score 4):

I think your regular expression is fine.  The error you have is the way you read from the file.  Also, you have it commented out in your post, don't know if that is a mistake or not.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_file = "words.txt";
open (my $MYFILE, "<", $data_file) or die "can't find file - $!";

while (my $line = <$MYFILE>)
{
    chomp($line);
    print "$line\n" if $line =~ m/.*a.*e.*i.*o.*u.*/i;
}

close ($MYFILE);
```

You should always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  You should also use the three-argument version of open to specify it is read only.

Comment: +1 for `use strict` and `use warnings`.  +1k if I could.  So many mysterious Perl bugs become obvious when you add those four words.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot This is true :).

Answer (score 0):

I would have done:

```
% perl -ne 'print if /a.*e.*i.*o.*u/' < words.txt
```

Use Perl as a Swiss Army Knife.

Actually, I would have done:

```
% cat words.txt | perl -ne 'print if /.*/' | head
```

Then when that showed me the first 10 lines of words.txt, I would have:

```
% cat words.txt | perl -ne 'print if /a/' | head
```

Then

```
% cat words.txt | perl -ne 'print if /a.*e/' | head
```

:

```
% cat words.txt | perl -ne 'print if /a.*e.*i.*o.*u/' | head
% cat words.txt | perl -ne 'print if /a.*e.*i.*o.*u/' | less
% cat words.txt | perl -ne 'print if /a.*e.*i.*o.*u/' | less > results.txt
```

As trivia, note that 'less' (and 'more') act as pass-thru's when they are not writing to a terminal.

This style develops your program one step at a time, where you can see the results at each step.

Answer (score 0):

MYFILE is in list context. So applying m// to a list will act on scalar context of MYFILE.